# Can't upload updated android application to play store. Previous certificate fingerprint is blank

Tags: android, apk, google-play

After I try to upload an updated APK to the play store I get this error:

> **Upload failed**
>   You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
>   [  ]
>   and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
>   [ SHA1: FB:BC:61:54:B3:26:6C:73:92:68:65:EA:0C:81:69:81:2B:39:21:66 ]

So I have to find a keystore with...no fingerprint. Can I upload an unsigned APK? I haven't updated the app in years, but I'm still using the only keystore I've ever used.

**Edit**, I downloaded the live app from the play store. I can't figure out how to get a signature fingerprint, but the keystore I'm using expires the exact same minute that the live application does (in 2036) so it's definitely the key I'm trying to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must have been some sort of error on Google's end. They fixed the problem on their end after I opened a support ticket.

My APK uploads now with no modification on my part.

Answer (score 0):

you can't upload an unsigned APK on GooglePlay.

[http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html][1]

Maybe your keystore expired. Do you remember the validity period you set when you originally generated it

Comment: 25+ years. Google won't let you upload an app that expires before 2033. Mine is good until 2036.

Comment: uh well. can't think of anything else

Answer (score 0):

this solution works for me (but you should find your original keystore)

1.download your orginal `apk` from play store

2.deplace your apk to `java\jdk...\bin`

3.open `cmd windows` and move to the directory with where your file `apk`

4.execute this comand `keytool -list-printcert -jarfile yourfile.apk` this command will return all information about your file `apk (keystore and password)`

5.find your keystore `(.jks)`

6.generate your new `apk` from your `keystore`